# how to drop down an element by python with selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to retrieve the data from the Unite Kingdom trade website. I have a small problem in one step. when my code open the the site, in one step I should click to the drop down menu then after that I choose to select which Chapter I need. My problem is that **I should select the drop down menu to make it activated**. Could you do me a favor and help me? How can I select the drop down menu. I wrote the code by **python selenium**. I am totally beginner in webscraping.

The website address: https://www.uktradeinfo.com/trade-data/ots-custom-table/

[image]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.uktradeinfo.com/trade-data/ots-custom-table/')
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="row-1"]/option[1]').click()      # Commodity Scroll bar         
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="row-2"]/option[4]').click()      # Country By (continent)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="row-3"]/option[1]').click()      # Add another dimention
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/fieldset[2]/details/summary').click()    #Change column headings
time.sleep(1)


time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("volumes-value").click()          # Value GBM should be unselected by this line
driver.find_element_by_id("volumes-net-mass").click()       # Net Mass (Kg) shoul be selected
time.sleep(1)


    # Chapter 2
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-group[1]/transform/div/div[2]/visual-container[5]/transform/div/div[2]/div[1]/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div/div').click()
```

Comment: What options are you trying to select?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire  chapters   1,2,4,7,10,12,15,20,23,38

Comment: I can't follow this step `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-group[1]/transform/div/div[2]/visual-container[5]/transform/div/div[2]/div[1]/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div/div').click()`. What are you trying to do in this step?

Comment: @undetected Selenium I wanted after opening the drop down check "I mean choose" chapter 2 . I don't know how to do it. Could you do me a favor and help me??

Comment: @SaiedVaygani Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: @undetected Selenium I have just only 19 reputation and it is forbidden for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is - that dropdown you are trying to click is in an iframe, so you need to switch to it. Also, it's good practice to wait for the element to load properly in page (be clickable, for example) before trying to locate them). The code below will also demonstrate the use of `Select`. The selenium/chromedriver setup is for linux, but you can adapt it to your own setup, just pay attention at imports, and at the code after defining the browser(driver, in your case):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with
import time as t


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.uktradeinfo.com/trade-data/ots-custom-table/'
browser.get(url)

## sortout cookie button
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-accept-cookies='true']"))).click()
    print("accepted cookies")
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button')
    
select_commodities = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='row-1']"))))
select_commodities.select_by_index(1)
print('selected commodities ')
extra_dimension_1 = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='row-2']"))))
extra_dimension_1.select_by_index(3)
print('added dimension country by continent')
extra_dimension_2 = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='row-3']"))))
extra_dimension_2.select_by_index(4)
print('added dimension by uk port')
# click the slicer slicer-dropdown-menu, which is in an iframe, so we need to switch to it
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Overseas Trade Statistics Power BI report']")))
t.sleep(2)
slicer = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slicer-restatement']")))[4]
t.sleep(10)
slicer.click()
print('clicked the slicer')
```

Once you're done with the iframe, don't forget to switch back to the main content, with `browser.switch_to.default_content()`. Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

EDIT: One more thing: selecting elements from that list will not be trivial: you can only click on the 7 or so which are in view, and if you try scrolling down, another group of 7 will be created, while the old group will dissapear from view (selenium logic at least). Your best bet would be to use the 'search' functionality which appears in the first row when you expand the list, search for the full item title/name, and select the first option, then move to the second element, etc. I don;t think there is a way to select them by index, as the list is live and index will change as you scroll.

Comment: @platipus_on_file First of all thank you so much from you that you spent time to solve my problem. Your program works. but I have to table on this page I don't know which one you tried to activate. I want the first one. I want first slicer down menu :)

Comment: @Barmar Could you do me a favor and help me in this project. I just want to click the drop down menu till it will be activated then I chose chapter one.

Comment: The code above clicks and opens Harmonized System Commodity Code, as you requested initially. Selecting items from that dropdown list is *not* trivial. I suggest get the full category names first, then try to locate them by name, scrolling down in a while loop and reinitializing the list on scroll.